# Letting twillio ring before it picks up

Tags: python, rest, twilio

I have just started using twillio. Im not sure if its the right tool for what I am trying.

Currently if I dial my number, there is no ring, it just picks up straight away. The reason I am mentioning this is because I would like it to first ring before it picks up. So my user can actually put down the phone before the call is connected and the person is billed.

Is this possible? My number is new, nothing has been setup or done to it.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here. You can actually use the `<Pause>` verb in TwiML to delay picking the call up. Check out the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause) and the examples at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

This is where Twilio gets tricky. Technically the call is picked up instantly, so there is no timeout to let it ring.

What you can do, is initialize the phone call with a timeout, and using the `Play` verb, use an MP3 recording of the standard ring before letting the program do it's thing.